# Java GMail api - java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, gmail, gmail-api

I'm using glassfish server 4.1 with java JDK 1.8. I use maven to build and deploy.

I made a form that triggers a controller to send an email using gmail api.

**The form that triggers the controller:**

```
<form method="post" action=GmailController>
        <td>Test API gmail</td>
        <td><input name="email" value="${requestScope.get("email")}" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Send email" /></td>
</form>
```

**The controller "GmailController":**

```
@WebServlet("/GmailController")
public class GmailController extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String email = request.getParameter("email");

    try {
        sendAnEmail("email_body", email, email); //custom method that uses gmail API
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

**The sendAnEmail method that calls GMail API functions:**

```
public static void sendAnEmail(String body, String from, String to) throws Exception {
    Gmail service = getGmailService();
    MimeMessage msg = createEmail(to, from, "Area", body);
    sendMessage(service, "email@example.com", msg);
```

}

When I submit the form that triggers the controller, I get a HTTP 500 error and glassfish displays :

> java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class

When I tested GMail API outside of my java glassfish web application, it worked correctly, by calling `sendAnEmail` in a java main.

I don't understand what can be causing this error because my class doesn't inherit from any other class except from `HttpServlet`.

When I comment the `sendAnEmail()` call, there is no errors, so the bug must not be because of `HttpServlet` inheritance.

What can be causing this error ?
How can I debug or get more informations about it ?

In server.log I don't get more informations, it shows the same error and tells the thread has stopped.

After some testing, exact same code on another computer and OS gives :

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.util.ClassInfo.getFieldInfos()Ljava/util/Collection;

Instead.

google-api-services-oauth2, google-api-services-gmail and google-api-client all are version 1.23.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Error: `java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class`**

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138136/cannot-inherit-from-final-class-error), you have managed to create a class that extends a superclass, where the superclass has been declared as `final`.

> The most likely cause is that you have a conflict between your build classpath and your launch classpath. In other words, you are compiling your subclass against a version of the superclass that is not `final`, and then running against a version that is `final`. The verifier is saying (correctly) that this is wrong.

**Error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.util.ClassInfo.getFieldInfos()Ljava/util/Collection;`**

Based from this [forum](https://forums.somethingawful.com/showthread.php?threadid=2780384&pagenumber=233&perpage=40#post460370823), your code is (indirectly) calling a method that didn't exist. Check your dependencies that you're using in your classpath.

Hope this helps!